# Perform unique row operation after a groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have been stuck to a problem where I have done all the groupby operation and got the resultant dataframe as shown below but the problem came in last operation of calculation of one additional column

Current dataframe:

```
code        industry               category     count     duration
2       Retail                      Mobile        4         7
3       Retail                      Tab           2         33
3       Health                      Mobile        5         103
2       Food                         TV           1         88
```

The question: Want an additional column `operation` which calculates the ratio of count of industry 'retail' for the specific `code` column entry

for example: code `2` has 2 `industry` entry retail and food so `operation` column should have value `4/(4+1) = 0.8` and similarly for code`3` as well as shown below

O/P:

```
code        industry               category     count     duration  operation
2       Retail                      Mobile        4         7         0.8
3       Retail                      Tab           2         33        -
3       Health                      Mobile        5         103       2/7 = 0.285
2       Food                         TV           1         88        -
```

Help on here as well that if I do just groupby I will miss out the information of `category` and `duration` also what would be better way to represent the `output df` there can been multiple industry and operation is limited to just `retail`

Comment: `df.groupby("code")["count"].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())`?  You can vectorize it a bit more by having `code` be an index and using index alignment after just finding `sum`.

Comment: @user3483203 can you please elaborate, your approach does not involve `industry` which is a essential factor

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single operation. But the way via a dictionary should work. Oh, and in advance for the other answerers the code to create the example dataframe.

```
st_l = [[2,'Retail','Mobile', 4, 7],
       [3,'Retail', 'Tab', 2, 33],
       [3,'Health', 'Mobile', 5, 103],
       [2,'Food', 'TV', 1, 88]]
df = pd.DataFrame(st_l, columns= 
     ['code','industry','category','count','duration'])
```

And now my attempt:

```
sums = df[['code', 'count']].groupby('code').sum().to_dict()['count']
df['operation'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['count']/sums[x['code']], axis=1)
```

Comment: have not considered `industry`? it is an essential factor for calculation

Comment: I'm not quite sure if i understand right than. My solution calculates it for all industries now. But if you only want to know retail and dno't want to see the others, you could add something like: df['operation'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['industry'] == 'retail' else x['operation'], axis=1)

Comment: But this would only delete values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with the total count of each code using [`groupby.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), and then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to find only the rows that have as their industry 'Retail' and perform your division:

```
df['total_per_code'] = df.groupby(['code'])['count'].transform('sum')
df.loc[df.industry.eq('Retail'), 'operation'] = df['count'].div(df.total_per_code)

df.drop('total_per_code',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

prints back:

```
  code industry category  count  duration  operation
0     2   Retail   Mobile      4         7   0.800000
1     3   Retail      Tab      2        33   0.285714
2     3   Health   Mobile      5       103        NaN
3     2     Food       TV      1        88        NaN
```